# MySQL query calculation problem after LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, left-join

I have two tables **user_point_logs** and **user_point_used_logs**
from there I want to get an output like this

```
╔══════╦═════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗══════════════╗
║ year ║month║ user_next_expire_date║ user_point_next_expire║minus         ║
╠══════╬═════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣══════════════╣
║2018  ║ 10  ║ 2018年10月27日        ║ 200                   ║110          ║
║      ║     ║                      ║                       ║              ║ 
╚══════╩═════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝══════════════╝
```

> here is relation user_point_logs.return_id = user_point_used_logs.id 
>   and user_point_used_logs.user_point_log_used_id = user_point_logs.id

**user_point_logs** table

```
╔════╦════════╦═════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║user_id ║point║expire_date║return_id ║
╠════╬════════╬═════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ 16087  ║ 100 ║1540649153 ║   null   ║
║  2 ║ 16087  ║ 100 ║ null      ║   1      ║
║  3 ║ 16087  ║ 10  ║ null      ║   2      ║
║  4 ║ 16087  ║ 100 ║ 1540649153║   null   ║ 
╚════╩════════╩═════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Table **user_point_used_logs**:

```
|-------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------|
| Id    | user_point_log_id     | user_point_log_used_id| point|
|-------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------|
| 1     |         2             |         2             | 100  |
|-------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------|
| 2     |         3             |         3             | 10   |
|-------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------|
```

I just tried to place some sample data.
Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_point_logs.expire_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS year, 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_point_logs.expire_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS month, 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT user_point_logs.expire_date ORDER BY user_point_logs.expire_date ASC
        SEPARATOR ','
      ), 
      ',', 
      1
    ), 
    '%Y年%m月%d日'
  ) AS user_next_expire_date, 
  SUM(user_point_logs.point) AS user_point_next_expire, 
  IF(
    SUM(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`) IS NULL, 
    0, 
    SUM(`user_point_used_logs`.`point`) 
  ) AS `minus` 
FROM `user_point_logs` 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM user_point_used_logs
  WHERE user_point_log_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT return_id
    FROM user_point_logs
    WHERE return_id IS NOT NULL
  )
) AS user_point_used_logs 
ON (`user_point_logs`.`id` = `user_point_used_logs`.`user_point_log_used_id`) 
WHERE `user_point_logs`.`user_id` = '16087' 
AND `user_point_logs`.`point` > 0
AND `user_point_logs`.`expire_date` > 1540464465 
AND (
  `user_point_logs`.`return_id` = 0 OR 
  `user_point_logs`.`return_id` IS NULL
)
GROUP BY `year`, `month`
```

The problem is that sometimes the calculation of the remaining point and minus are not getting the actual result. In my fiddle you will see user_point_next_expire 200 but minus 0.
But there minus should have been 100.

Please tell me if is there anything wrong in my query or not.

Here is my sample data set...

```
CREATE TABLE user_point_logs (
  id          int NOT NULL,
  user_id     int NOT NULL,
  point       int(11) NOT NULL,
  expire_date int DEFAULT NULL,
  return_id   int DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user_point_used_logs (
  id                      int NOT NULL,
  user_point_log_id       int NOT NULL,
  user_point_log_used_id  int DEFAULT '0' ,
  point                   int NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO user_point_used_logs 
  (id,  user_point_log_id,  user_point_log_used_id, point) 
VALUES 
  (1,   2,                  2,                      100),
  (2,   3,                  3,                      10);

INSERT INTO user_point_logs 
  (id,  user_id,  point,  expire_date,  return_id) 
VALUES
  (1,   16087,    100,    1540649153,   NULL),
  (2,   16087,    100,    NULL      ,   1   ),
  (3,   16087,     10,    NULL      ,   2   ),
  (4,   16083,    100,    1540649153,   NULL),
  (5,   16087,    100,    1540649153,   NULL);
```

..and [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9GfbiCvmDnQbj89aPi5tuM/2) of same

Comment: What is the point of the `user_point_used_logs` table? It doesn't seem to contain any information that's not already in `user_point_logs`.

Comment: @Nick here is relation user_point_logs.return_id = user_point_used_logs.id  and user_point_used_logs.user_point_log_used_id = user_point_logs.id

Comment: Please do not delete & repost questions. Just edit them. My comment from before stil applies: You do not clearly explain how the result is a function of the inputs.

Comment: @philipxy sorry for new post my bad. I can't understand yours words"how the result is a function of the inputs" I already displayed how I want  my result in my question first table. Here problem minus value is not coming from my query I applied.

Comment: It is not obvious what query would return your example output table from your example input tables. Explain what the rows should be in the output table regardless of what rows are in the input tables. output = f (user_point_logs, user_point_used_logs). Explain function f, the query.

Comment: I think part of the confusion (certainly my confusion) is that the problem seems so much simpler than the query that's used to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I have with this question is I cannot see what part of the problem the following fails to solve:

```
SELECT MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(expire_date)) dt
     , SUM(CASE WHEN expire_date < UTC_TIMESTAMP() THEN point END) a
     , SUM(CASE WHEN expire_date IS NULL THEN point END) b
  FROM user_point_logs
 WHERE user_id = 16087
 GROUP 
    BY user_id;
```

Comment: I need this condition also  WHERE `user_point_logs`.`expire_date` > currenttime() when I used that your b colum become null

Comment: @LemonKazi You seem to want times when expire_date < UTC_TIMESTAMP (see edit) - but maybe I've misunderstood